# How to Filter listbox data to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, winforms, c#-4.0

I am trying to create List box filter program but I am not getting
exact result. In this listbox1 I want paste some record from excel data and if any
duplicate data is there then it should be filter and display in
listbox2.

In this picture i want show Listbox1 data after filter it should
display in Listbox2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcGGd.png

This is the code.

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var filter = listBox1.Items.Cast<String>().ToList();
                listBox1.BeginUpdate();
                listBox1.Items.Clear();
                foreach(string str in filter)
                {
                    if(str.Contains(textBox1.Text))
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(str);
                    }
                }
                listBox1.EndUpdate();
            }
```

Comment: your code illogicality. if you want got t.extBox1.Text whether include in listBox1.Items, need using `if (listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Any(p=>p==textBox1.Text)){ listBox2.Items.Add(textBox1.Text) }`

Comment: hello  Johan Shen.
in my code i have only one listbox wich is right i kept and left side i kept textbox.
but your code you are adding listbox2 which is not full fill in my code.
so can you send me your full code.

Comment: Please clear your question, what type of filter do you try to do? only if the text in your textbox is contain in the list item of somthing else? And you want it to filter to listbox2 or to listbox1?